# QGIS coordinate system in meters

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I am new to working on spatial data. Someone sent me a series of coordinates x,y in meters of particular locations in London. Here is an example:

| X (m) | Y (m) |
| --- | --- |
| 534849 | 177512 |

The person was able to plot these coordinates in QGIS.

I was expecting the coordinates to be longitude and latitude which I thought were measured in degrees. I'm also mindful that these coordinates could still be used in QGIS.

Can you clarify this for me and explain how I could actually change the coordinate system in QGIS from degrees to meters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These coordinates (Eastings/Northings) are in OSGB36 British National Grid - load in https://epsg.io/27700 and reproject **(CRS)** to WGS84 in QGIS.

[image]

[image]

sample data used here was downloaded from https://digitalmaptiles.ukmapcentre.com/samples-products.html